# Deleting recently closed tabs using Chrome's Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on an extension that removes history of specific tabs that my extension closes.

Till now this has been removed from history using:

```
chrome.tabs.remove(tab, function() { });
chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: url});
```

The issue is that even though the websites are not in history, they still appear in the recently closed tabs/as well as omnibox text prediction (though I have noticed that they don't have any picture, just text)

Is there a way to delete the specifically closed tabs from:

1. recently closed tabs and
2. wipe any trace of it from the omnibox predictive text as well?

Maybe using the chrome.browsingData API ?

Comment: Can you provide your logs?

Comment: Hello abielita, here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/BYtrn

Comment: I am not sure, but think [browsingData.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData#method-remove) helps you. And you have to work with very short `since` interval. Less than a second.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks