# Javascript sequential execution for chrome after loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

For a number of tabs that satisfy check > 0,

I need 3 operations to happen sequentially

1.chrome.history.deleteUrl(the url is removed from history)

2.chrome.tab.update(the tab is renamed to what i want)

3.Then the tab is closed.

Right now, it seems that (number 2) chrome.tabs.update does not happen fast enough.

The tab is closed and still appears in the "recently closed tabs" even though absent from history.

I have tried to add a timeout to make it execute after a second but the issue is that after 1 second only the last tab will be closed.

```
   if (check>0){
//#1
chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: url});
//#2
chrome.tabs.update(tab,{url:"html/test.html"});
//#3
cleanup(tab);
//var timing = setTimeout(cleanup, 1000);
function cleanup(z) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(z);
}
}
```

Is there a way to force #3 to execute after #2 has finished loading completely?

Maybe storing all tabs in an array then executing the whole remove in one go ?

Comment: use chrome.tabs.update(tab,{url:"html/test.html"}, cleanup);

Comment: @juvian : Thanks! but still the same even with cleanup(tab)

Comment: Well, deleteUrl is also async so add a callback to that as well

Comment: chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: url}, function(tab){chrome.tabs.update(tab,{url:"html/test.html"}, chrome.tabs.remove)})

Comment: doesn't work, seems the update doesn't have time to load and gets closed by the remove

Comment: after a lot of searching, seems your method won't work. Even if you remove the url, then you are closing the tab which triggers the recently closed addition of that tab. For the correct way of doing it, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730967/deleting-recently-closed-tabs-using-chromes-javascript-api comments

Comment: I made the other thread as well..

Comment: Well, did you use browsingdata.remove?