# How to clear history entries on tab close?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension with an options tab that loads an online webpage within a sandboxed iframe element. Whenever a user clicks on some link inside the iframe, the browser creates a new history entry and the browser's back/forward button gets activated.

I want to clear all history entries created once the user closes the tab, and if possible, stop the browser from adding the tab to the "History -> Recently Closed" menu.

I've experimented with different APIs within the browser console, and none of the following seems to be working as intended:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    // Using the `chrome.history` API
    chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: 'https://example.tld/'}, console.log);

    // Using the `chrome.browsingData` API
    chrome.browsingData.removeHistory({
      "since": (new Date()).getTime() - 1000000
    }, console.log);
};
```

While this executes successfully with no errors whatsoever, I can still restore the tab via "History -> Recently Closed" and use the back/forward buttons to navigate back to URLs loaded inside the iframe element (i.e., "https://example.tld/"). How can I stop this behavior?

Note: Both of the "history" and "browsingData" permissions are acquired through the "manifest.json" file.

Comment: `onunload` is for quick synchronous cleanup so it won't work for chrome API with asynchronous callbacks. Also, content scripts cannot access chrome.browsingData. You need a background page (or an event page) and specialized events from [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), see also the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Ref https://superuser.com/q/359879/78897

Answer (score 1):

The same scenario was raised in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730967/deleting-recently-closed-tabs-using-chromes-javascript-api).

> Is there a way to delete the specifically closed tabs from:
>
> 1. recently closed tabs and
> 2. wipe any trace of it from the omnibox predictive text as well?

Suggested action is to use [browsingData.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData#method-remove).

```
chrome.browsingData.remove( RemovalOptions options, DataTypeSet dataToRemove, function callback)
```

Comment: But RemovalOptions only allow setting the time.